# iOS crash report - mediaserverd: RPCTimeout message received to terminate

Tags: ios, audio, crash

I see some strange crash reports which I couldn't understand much what it is. I believe it is something related to audio service in iOS. I am working on a audio app where each record is played in FIFO order. Is the crash log is something to do with my app? Here is the snippet of the crash report

```
Incident Identifier: 56987C0E-3207-43E2-A30F-CA62DACA341B
CrashReporter Key:   39cfbba1b55bae50131e2b43a44f512635ffdedc
Hardware Model:      iPod5,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Kernel version:      Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Wed Feb 13 21:37:47 PST 2013; root:xnu-2107.7.55.2.2~1/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8942X
Date:                2013-09-20 19:48:08 +0530
Exception Code:      0xbe18d1ee
Reason:              mediaserverd: RPCTimeout message received to terminate [4773] with reason 'fig rpc timeout -- playerremote_CopyProperty [ NowPlayingAppPID ]'
Thermal Level:       0
Thermal Sensors:    3284 3517 3539 3165 3594

Frontmost process PID:    68
Jetsam Level:              0
Free Pages:            21115
Active Pages:          22813
Inactive Pages:        14162
Purgeable Pages:        1390
Wired Pages:           21867
Speculative Pages:       765
Throttled Pages:       47808
Busy Buffer Count:         0
Pages Wanted:              0
Pages Reclaimed:           0

Process 0 info:
    resident memory bytes:  70152192
    page faults:              10157
    page-ins:                     0
    copy-on-write faults:         0
    user   time in task: 201946.766630 seconds
    system time in task:     0.000000 seconds

Process 0 kernel_task threads:
thread 0x1 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x803262e0
    thread priority:          92
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 800622ed
    user   time in thread:     1.240739 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x2 TH_RUN|TH_IDLE 0
    thread priority:           0
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 800256c9
    user   time in thread: 98035.929317 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x3 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x80022059
    thread priority:          95
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80022059
    user   time in thread:    20.278736 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x4 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x80300c20
    thread priority:          80
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 8002cf39
    user   time in thread:     6.273227 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x5 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x80300c28
    thread priority:          93
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 8002d135
    user   time in thread:     0.005678 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x6 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0
    thread priority:          94
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 8002fc65
    user   time in thread:     0.202646 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x7 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0xcbaea45c
    thread priority:          95
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel 0x80024cab 0x800244d9 0x80033173 0x8008655c
    user   time in thread:     0.000296 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x8 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ccda544
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000012 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0xb TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8cd7ee04
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:   426.026233 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x1b TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8cd2e33c
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000021 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x20 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x803187fc
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 801e1c79
    user   time in thread:     0.000019 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x21 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8cd8c01c
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.038029 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x22 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ce2cea4
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000011 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x2a TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ce2c6ac
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel 0x80024cab 0x800244d9 0x80256b19 0x8008655c
    user   time in thread:     0.000019 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x2e TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ce3f134
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000019 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x62 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8cdf6044
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     8.861949 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x64 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ce8f724
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000018 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x65 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ce8f6d4
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel 0x80024cab 0x800244d9 0x80256b19 0x8008655c
    user   time in thread:    10.040660 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x66 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ce8f47c
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     2.540202 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x67 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ce8f2c4
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.250538 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x68 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8cf46ea4
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000010 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x69 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8cf46d64
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000009 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x6a TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8cf46c4c
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.048119 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x6b TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8cf46abc
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000009 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x6c TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8cf468dc
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000009 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x6e TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8cf46634
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:    36.630748 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x6f TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8cf46404
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:    36.139442 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x71 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8cf4610c
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000021 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x73 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8cef5b84
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.106043 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x74 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ceb9cec
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000012 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x75 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ceb992c
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000010 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x76 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ceb9454
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000010 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x78 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ced3ef4
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000020 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x79 TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ced3c4c
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000013 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x7a TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ced39a4
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     6.925023 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x7b TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ced36fc
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.000009 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
thread 0x7c TH_WAIT|TH_UNINT 0x8ced3134
    thread priority:          81
    thread sched flags:     none
    kernel cont 80256add
    user   time in thread:     0.009044 seconds
    system time in thread:     0.000000 seconds
```

Please can someone explain what is this?

Thanks